# Memory allocation on object creation

Tags: c#

how much memory it will be allocated in stack as well as in heap when we instantiate the class/struct Student?

I guess id = 4 bytes reference (32 bit machine) and name = 4 bytes reference and facultyAdvisor = 4 bytes reference. So totally 12 bytes in stack and actual size will be in heap. this heap size may vary depends upon the value that we assign to the fields(id, name, facultyAdvisor) that uses object obj(Student obj = new Student())

The same is for struct also right?

```
public class Student { int id; string name; Professor facultyAdvisor; }

public struct Student { int id; string name; Professor facultyAdvisor; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 32 bit CLR (references would be 64 bit on 64 bit CLR) and only taking into account heap allocation for Student

**class Student{} class Professor{}**

- Stack: 4 bytes
- Heap: 4 bytes (int) + 4 bytes (Professor Reference) + 4 bytes (string reference) + 12 bytes (object header)  = 24 bytes

**class Student{} struct Professor{}**

- Stack: 4 bytes
- Heap: 4 bytes (int) + size of Processor + 4 bytes (string reference) + 12 bytes (object header)  =   ?? bytes

**struct Student{} class Professor{}**

- Stack: 4 bytes (int) + 4 bytes (string reference) + 4 bytes (Professor reference) = 12 bytes
- Heap: 0 bytes

**struct Student{} struct Professor{}**

- Stack: 4 bytes (int) + 4 bytes (string reference) + size of Professor = ?? bytes
- Heap: 0 bytes

Comment: Thanks Jon - for some reason I missed the Name was there - edited

Comment: class Student{} class Professor{}

    Stack: 4 bytes
    Heap: 4 bytes (int) + 4 bytes (Professor Reference) + 4 bytes (string reference) + 12 bytes (object header) = 24 bytes. 
In this case 4 bytes (Professor Reference) will be in the heap? If so, where the actual object lives?
Also, As u said 4 bytes in stack, will this 4 byte stack reference points to all the fields(id,name and facultyAdvisor). Is it possible?

Comment: 4 bytes on stack are the Student reference which points to the student object on the heap (with all its fields), professor reference is allocated with the Student but the professor object is a separate allocation on the heap

Comment: Hi, since the professor object is a separate allocation on the heap, its reference is supposed to be stored on the stack right? how it could be along with the student object which is in heap.

Comment: no - the reference to the professor is part of the state of the student and so is stored with the student object on the heap

Comment: Student s = new Student();
s.facultyAdviser;
How come the 4 byte reference s(which is in the stack ) knows the address of the reference facultyAdviser. Where this 4 byte s reference keep track the addresses of facultyAdviser reference.

Comment: The reference on the stack is a pointer to an area of memory on the heap. This memory is formatted according to the definition of a Student (int, string reference, Professor reference). The CLR allocates enough memory on the heap to store this state and it gets zero'd and initialized in the constructor. The Professor reference is set and stored in the piece of student memory and points to the  actual professor object

Answer (score 5):

First note that the [stack and the heap are implementation details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx)... as is the size of the object. But in the current implementation, all the data for the *fields* within `Student` when it's a class are on the heap. There's an object overhead as well as the memory taken for the fields, but all of that will be on the heap.

If you're keeping a *reference* to the new instance, and you're keeping it in an uncaptured local variable not in an iterator block or async method, that reference would be on the stack (in the current implementation) so it would be 4 bytes on a 32-bit CLR.

When `Student` is a struct, things change somewhat:

- The location of the data (stack or heap) depends on how the value is being used - if it's stored in an instance variable in a class, for example, it will be on the heap along with the rest of the data; if it's in a local variable (again, uncaptured and not in an iterator block or async method) then it'll be on the stack
- You're not creating a separate *object*, just a *value*, so there's no extra overhead - it really would just take 12 bytes (assuming `Professor` is a reference type)

I have a couple of articles/posts you may find useful:

- [Memory and object overheads](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings.aspx) (particularly of strings, but other types too)
- [What goes where](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/memory.html) - the stack and the heap, remembering again that it's an implementation detail

EDIT: Addressing the `Professor` issue, assuming `Professor` is a class - unless a `Professor` object is explicitly created, the reference in `Student` will simply be null. Creating a new `Student` does *not* automatically create a new `Professor` just because there's a field of that type. The reference to the `Professor` is just part of the data for `Student` - it lives wherever the `id` lives - so if `Student` is a class, then the reference only exists on the heap, and if `Student` is a struct then it depends on where the `Student` value is created, as listed above.

Comment: Edited the question. Kindly answer

Comment: @Alavudeen: Done, although I'm not quite sure I understood the edited question. If my edit doesn't satisfy you, please clarify the question.

Comment: I clarified with your answer for my edited question. But still not able to come to conclusion

Comment: @Alavudeen: Yes, I'm afraid so. Your question doesn't really make sense in terms of English - I appreciate it's probably not your first language, but it does make it hard to answer :( Have you read the articles I linked to? They cover all of this in a lot of detail. If you've read those thoroughly and still have questions, please post a more specific piece of code - ideally a complete program - and very specific questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GC.GetTotalMemory(true)` calls to measure memory consumption before and after instantiation to measure heap allocation